# Visual Studio having trouble painting SSIS tasks

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2005, ssis

I've got this weird behavior in Visual Studio 2005 when working with SSIS packages. Visual Studio appears to be having problems painting/repainting the tasks.

When I open a package, I see the label of the task items and the line connecting tasks, but I don't see the box outline or the icon of the task type. When I click on the task item, the outline and icon appear. If I minimize the screen and then maximize it, they disappear again.

The problems exists if I bounce my machine and load Visual Studio by itself. I don't have the problem with any other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it couple times, and in both cases the problem disappeared after I installed the latest video drivers.